# Stupid Query: Oxygen XML Editor debugger configuration

Tags: oxygenxml

I previously worked on a project where I included the following in an xslt:

```
<xsl:variable name="fileList" select="collection('./in?select=*_A_*_J.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
```

And that worked fine.

But now no matter which project I open, whenever I use the debugger to do a test run I get the following error in the 'Debugger Errors' pane:

Cannot evaluate the XPath expression 'collection('./in?select=*_A_*_J.xml;recurse=yes')' for parameter '$fileList'.

(Because the 'in' subdirectory doesn't exist.)

It doesn't stop anything from running, it just pops up the error then runs the debugger as normal.

I must have set some sort of global property looking for $fileList, right? But I have no idea what I did, how I did it, or how to turn it off. What do I need to change to make the error stop?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look in the Debugger XWatch view, it might contain that expreesion added as a watch expression.